# Is XNA a good place to learn 3d game programming?

Tags: c#, xna

I want to  explore 3D game development in XNA, but I'm curious if this is best for me. I haven't learned C#, but I want to explore my options before diving in. I have a lot of experience in the C programming language, along with some basics or minor experience in other languages. Which means that the object oriented framework that C# has may be a huge change from what I'm used to. I need to learn it anyways for future jobs and college, so this might would be a good incentive. I have programmed two games using the SDL 2.0 mixer and SDL 2.0 frameworks, which have given me a good basis of the knowledge of how 2D games are structured. I have learned about sprites, frame rate, event polling/handling, frame rendering, among other things. I am still highly lacking in mathematics related to game development and the physics behind it. That leads to my next point of concern if I do decide to learn XNA, is if it would help me more easily learn those things faster? Writing for my games in C, I was always having to write interfaces on top of interfaces, but at least I had to understand what I was writing. With C#, I'm concerned it would abstract most of the mathematics I really want to glean from it. You may ask that if I'm so concerned, why don't I just learn linear algebra and OpenGL/DirectX/whatever in C? Well, I'm hoping to avoid that, since even though I was able to make a decent game, I'm still very much lacking in how to do more advanced game development and code structuring. This was very obvious to me after working on one of my game projects for about half a year.

Comment: XNA is no longer supported, and some call it dead

Comment: "According to an email sent on 31 January 2013, XNA is no longer actively being developed, and it is not supported under the new "Metro interface" layers of Windows 8 nor on the Windows RT platform." (from [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA)).

Comment: use Unity3D multi platform

Comment: @Tsukasa Unity3D is hardly "cheap".

Comment: Hi @Name you seem new here. This question is unfortunately not really suited to Stack Overflow - not because it isn't interesting or useful - but because it's a request for opinions and suggestions (as well as being a whole slew of questions all bundled into one blob). Stack Overflow works best with single, specific, technical questions, and everything else is unfortunately rigorously removed. So don't be surprised if your questions is shortly closed. It's not personal - just that this is the wrong place for what you're after.

Comment: Unity3D has a free version and works just fine.

Answer (score 6):

MS has [ceased supporting XNA](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/185894/Its_official_XNA_is_dead.php) going forward. If you want to stick with XNA, have a look at [MonoGame](http://monogame.net/), which is an open-source version of XNA.